# Reduced Rings and Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, modules

Still trying to get my head around certain foundational concepts in algebraic geometry here, so pray bear with me...

Is it true to say that if $R$ is a ring, then every (associative) algebra over $R$ does itself have the structure of a ring?

Furthermore, provided the above holds water, is it true to say that if $R$ is reduced, then any $R$-algebra, regarded as a ring, is also reduced?

I look forward to your responses.

Comment: What are you using as the definition of associative algebra? For the second, consider the ring $R=\mathbb{C}[x]$ and the $R$-algebra $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$

Comment: For the first question: yes: an associative $R$-algebra is alternatively defined as a ring homomorphism $R\to S$.

Comment: Ah! I had never come across that particular definition of an $R$-algebra before! Yes, I think that I should be able to work it out from there! Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every major definition of an associative  algebra $A$ over a (commutative) ring $R$ makes $A$ a ring.

Every ring is a $\mathbb Z$ algebra, and $\mathbb Z$ is reduced, so if algebras over reduced rings were reduced, all rings would be reduced.

As someone already gave in the comments, $R[x]/(x^2)$ is a simple example of an $R$ algebra that isn’t reduced, and $R$ can be any nonzero commutative ring, even a reduced one.

Comment: Cheers for the comment. Yes, and I cannot deny that this very much actually annoys me---not your comments of course, I much appreciate them---because then it would appear to be that there are two inequivalent different definitions of what a *reduced algebra* is. One says that a reduced algebra is an algebra without nilpotent elements, and the other says that a reduced algebra is an algebra over a reduced ring. Since there clearly exists algebras that are reduced according to the one definition but not the other (for instance, the example you have stated, $R[x]/(x^2)$), damned, that's annoying!

Comment: @StormyTeacup: "Reduced algebra" never means "algebra over a reduced ring"; it always means "algebra that is reduced as a ring".  More generally, when talking about properties of an algebra, they always are about the algebra itself, not about the ring it is an algebra over.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Well that's how I interpreted Wikipedia's definition "A commutative algebra over a commutative ring is called a reduced algebra if its underlying ring is reduced", and even if you want to argue that "Well, Wikipedia is Wikipedia, you cannot trust everything on it" (which is fair enough), I have found the same definition elsewhere, like in Thierry Vialar's *Handbook of Mathematics*. But perhaps I have simply misunderstood the term "underlying ring", and that what is meant is not *the ring the algebra is over*, but rather *the algebra itself when viewed as a ring*?

Comment: @EricWofsey: Follow up! A quick googling led me to this page: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Underlying_Ring_of_Associative_Algebra which makes very clear that I had indeed misunderstood the term "underlying algebra". Very nice to have all this sorted out! :)